# ModuleNotFoundError in vs code Frappe import

Tags: python-3.x, frappe, frappe-charts

Unfortunately, I always get this error message with Frappe, so I ask you that you can maybe help me and give me a few types. Thank you and I'll be happy to wait for your answer. Thanks
Error:

1. Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
   No module named 'frappe'
   File "/home/erp/frappe-bench/apps/erpnextfints/erpnextfints/erpnextfints/doctype/fints_import/fints_import.py", line 7, in
   import frappe

```py
import frappe
from frappe import _
from frappe.model.document import Document
from frappe.utils import now_datetime, get_datetime
```

2. Import "frappe.model.document" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports***`

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) 2019, jHetzer and contributors
# For license information, please see license.txt

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import frappe
from frappe import _
from frappe.model.document import Document
from frappe.utils import now_datetime, get_datetime


class FinTSImport(Document):
    def validate_past(self, date, field_name):
        if isinstance(date, str):
            date = get_datetime(date).date()
        if date >= now_datetime().date():
            frappe.msgprint(
                _("'{0}' needs to be in the past").format(field_name)
            )
            return False
        if (now_datetime().date() - date).days >= 90:
            frappe.msgprint(
                _("'{0}' is more then 90 days in the past").format(field_name)
            )
            return False
        return True

    def before_save(self):
        status = True
        if self.from_date is not None:
            status = self.validate_past(self.from_date, "From Date")

            if self.to_date is not None:
                from_date = get_datetime(self.from_date).date()
                if from_date > get_datetime(self.to_date).date():
                    status = False
                    frappe.msgprint(_(
                        "'From Date' needs to be further in the past"
                        " then 'To Date'"))
        if self.to_date is not None:
            if not self.validate_past(self.to_date, "To Date"):
                status = False

        if not status:
            frappe.throw(_("Validation of dates failed"))

    def validate(self):
        self.before_save()
```

---

Screenshot of VS Code:

[image]

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Each Bench has it's own Python `env` which is where Frappe apps & their Python dependencies are installed. This directory can be found under the respective bench's root - `/home/erp/frappe-bench` in your case.

You have tell VS Code to use the Python interpreter from that environment. You can do that by either

- Manually setting the interpreter for your session

You may follow the instructions mentioned in [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) or [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqTsFOtZiQI&ab_channel=GalvanizeDataScience).

- Changing your current working directory

Simply cd into your bench and open VS Ccode from there - `cd /home/erp/frappe-bench && code .` and VS Code detects the env folder automatically and uses it as the active interpreter.

Comment: Changing my current directory did the trick. Thanks gavin